# Trouble Connecting USB Wireless Adapter via Bridged Adapter in VirtualBox for Kali Linux

Tags: linux, networking, virtual-machine, virtualbox, kali-linux

How can I properly configure and connect a Wireless Adapter (supporting monitor mode) in Kali Linux running on VirtualBox?

I'm facing an issue where, before launching Kali, I configure the network settings in VirtualBox to use my TP-Link Wireless Adapter in Bridge Adapter mode. However, upon launching Kali, the system recognizes a Media Tek Wi-Fi 6 adapter instead of my TP-Link, despite no changes made by me. Interestingly, upon closing Kali, the settings revert back to recognizing the TP-Link adapter.

I've attempted to address this by modifying settings in the Virtual Network Editor (vmnetcfg.exe) of VMware, adding VMnet0 with the TP-Link adapter specified in the Bridged section. However, upon relaunching Kali in VirtualBox, the settings seem to reset to default, with a different configuration displayed.

Here are the steps I've taken:

Connected the Wireless Adapter (supporting Monitor Mode) to the USB port.
Configured VirtualBox settings for the Kali VM: Settings -> Network -> Adapter1 -> Bridged Adapter -> Selected TP-Link Wireless USB Adapter (I also tried changing the MAC address to the host address in Advanced settings).
Launched Kali.
Checked interface using ifconfig command, confirming wlan0 in monitor mode.
Unable to establish internet connection; Kali cannot connect to the adapter.
Attempts to fix:

Adjusted VMware settings in the Virtual Network Editor, assigning the adapter to the Bridged section. No success.
Completely reinstalled VirtualBox and Kali Linux.
Utilized VMware program (vmnetcfg.exe) to assign my adapter to VMnet0 in Bridged mode. However, upon relaunching Kali, the adapter does not persist in the settings.
Seeking guidance on the correct procedure to ensure proper recognition and utilization of the Wireless Adapter in Kali Linux within the VirtualBox environment. Any general instructions or insights would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install driver for TP Link on your kali machine.

Connect WiFi Adapter and type this:

```
lsusb
```

Find your device name and type:

```
sudo apt search realtek
```

You need to find repository name of your device from lsusb command.

Install correct driver for your device:

```
sudo apt install realtek-rtl8188eus-dkms
```